# Azure Logic Apps - Timeout issue

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I have created a Azure Logic apps to pull data from a REST API and populate a Azure SQL Database to process some data and push result to Dynamics 365. I have around 6000 rows from REST API and I have created 2 logic apps, one pulls data as paged (each page having 10 records) and using a do until loop to process each set. I'm calling another logic app 2 from DO UNTIL loop and passing the paged records which inserts record in to SQL Database.

The issue i'm encountering is the Main logic app times out after 2 minutes.(It process around 600 rows and times out.)

I came across this article which explains various patterns related to managing long running process. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-create-api-app

What would be the best approach to executing long running tasks without time out issues?

Answer (score 1):

Your REST API should follow async pattern by returning 202 with a retry-after & location header, see more at: https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-create-api-app

Or, your REST API can be of webhook kind, so Logic Apps can provide a callback url for you to invoke once the processing is completed.

Comment: Thanks Derek for your response. The article I shared has some info but i'm looking for some good example to implement call back in logic apps flow.